# Where are the AR Markers for Bravely Second?

Tags: bravely-second

I completed the game and got what I think is the false ending. Along with New Game Plus, I have the AR Movie option on the title screen for my save data.

When I go into it, I get a message telling me I can go to http://www.nintendo.co.uk/bravelysecond to get them. When I go to that URL on my PC to download and print out the AR Markers, the URL changes to https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Games/Nintendo-3DS/Bravely-Second-End-Layer-1027213.html

I can't see anything on any of the pages or the official site about these AR Markers while the [Bravely Default site](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Games/Nintendo-3DS/Bravely-Default-813488.html) has a link/button before the "What you need to know" section which had the AR Cards for Bravely Default.

I know there has to be at least one different card, as the example card shown is Pope Agnès not Vestal Agnès.

Where are these AR Markers that are supposed to be on the website?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single AR Marker, sounds like there should be more though.

http://bravelysecond.nintendo.com/assets/downloads/arcard.pdf

Comment: i am curious if bravelysecond.nintendo.com was the url that was given with the US version of the game because the rating at the bottom is the US Rating. but that card is the same as the example one that's shown in the game